# Timer in xamarin app speeds up and slows down

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im creating ccountdown timer in xamarin.forms. [image]
The problem is when I pause the timer and next I'll start the timer, it speeds up and slows down and it happens the whole time. It should goes every second but why  does it speed up sometimes ever 2/4 seconds ?
The code below:

```
 bool Value =false;
 int counter =120;
 private void RunTimer(Boolean Value)
 {
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () => 
  {
    If(Value)
    {
      counter--;
      if(counter <=0)
      {
        counter = 120;
        MainText.Text = dt.AddSeconds(counter).ToString("mm:ss");
      }
      MainText.Text = dt.AddSeconds(counter).ToString("mm:ss");
      
    }
    return true;
 }
 return false;
});
   
 

  private void Start_Pause(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if(value == false)
   {
     RunTimer(true);
     Value = true;
   }
   else
   { 
     RunTimer(false);
     Value = false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: use `System.Timers.Timer`

Comment: How should I write it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainText.Text = dt.AddSeconds(counter).ToString("mm:ss");` <-- This is incorrect. Computer timers are never precise. Instead compute the `DateTime end` value once, and recompute remaining time by subtracing  `DateTime.Now` on every tick (instead of counting imprecise time periods yourself).

Change your code to something like this:

```
private void RunTimer(Boolean value)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime end   = start.AddSeconds( 120 );

    Device.StartTimer(
        interval: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 100 ),
        callback: () => 
    {
        TimeSpan remaining = end - DateTime.Now;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => 
        {
            this.MainText.Text = remaining.ToString("mm:ss");
        });
        
        return remaining >= TimeSpan.Zero;
    });
}
```

- I'm using `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 100 )` to ensure the label's text is invalidated closer to when the `remaining` value actually changes to counteract jitter in the system.
- Using `return remaining >= TimeSpan.Zero;` will stop the countdown as soon as `end` is passed.
- [The documentation says that all UI interactions inside `StartTimer` must be done with `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms).

Comment: How should it look with code above because I can't combine your idea with the structure of my code

Comment: @RObertos12 How is my `RunTimer` method incompatible with yours?